# Get 1st day of the Current Quarter

Tags: xcode6, nsdatecomponents

is there a way to get the first date of the current quarter of the year? I already know how to get the current Day of the week, month and year... i use this code:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:
                          NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear |
                          NSCalendarUnitYear|
                          NSCalendarUnitMonth|
                          NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth|
                          NSCalendarUnitWeekday
                                     fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comps setWeekday:2]; // 2: monday
NSDate * firstDayOfTheWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps setWeekday:1]; // 1: Sunday
NSDate *lastDayOfTheWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps setDay:1];
NSDate * firstDayOfTheMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm... It seems that using:

```
[comps setMonth:1];
```

is a buyable option provided, I determine the current month to plot the quarter (and encapsulate it into a switch statement), guess this might be easier but, what about other countries that have different way of measuring the "Quarter". for my current requirement, this will have to do but if someone can give me a better way of getting the current date of the current quarter.